# PHP move_uploaded_file permission denied only on RHEL

Tags: permissions, rhel, apache-httpd, php

my PHP script is using to register new user with his photo.

On Debian, everything was fine, but when I installed on my server RHEL, problems has begun.

Directory /tmp/ rights are 777 and "upload/" has 777 with chown apache:apache.

below is fragment of httpd's error_log:

> [Wed Jun 07 15:25:29.363766 2017] [:error] [pid 22867] [client
> 10.31.242.73:49624] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(upload/1268_org.jpg): failed to open stream:
> Permission denied in /var/www/html/inc/classes/user.inc.php on line
> 76, referer: http://10.31.242.72/index2.php?mnu=10041
>
> [Wed Jun 07 15:25:29.363808 2017] [:error] [pid 22867] [client 10.31.242.73:49624] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpmY6k8j' to 'upload/1268_org.jpg' in /var/www/html/inc/classes/user.inc.php on line 76, referer: http://10.31.242.72/index2.php?mnu=10041

I don't have any idea, what's wrong with it. Maybe I skipped something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution on [this website](http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/configuring-selinux-policies-for-apache-web-servers/)
It was `SELinux`'s blame. I just added httpd_sys_rw_content_t to upload directory by typing: `semanage fcontext -a httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/html/upload(/.*)?"`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `chdir()` before moving the file? If you didn't, the file is going to me moved to 'upload/1268_org.jpg', but relative to /var/www/html/inc/classes, which result in moving to `/var/www/html/inc/classes/upload/1268_org.jpg`, and is definitely not your intended location.

Solution: chdir before moving, or use absolute path.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't a problem :<  `getcwd()` function shows directory `/var/www/html/`. Even after changing to absolute path, problem is this same :<