# RHEL7 & PHP: File is not uploading (even into /tmp/)

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, php, tmp, upload

After few days, since I asked this question:
[LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369749/php-move-uploaded-file-permission-denied-only-on-rhel/369774)
I realized, that maybe it's another problem.

I used package `inotifywait` to check, is a temporary file generating after sending html form. Unfortunately temp file is not creating, after clicking "upload" button in my form, but I don't know why, because even I had turned off firewall (I thought that it is a problem - I was wrong). Maybe someone has this same problem?

---

OS is newly installed, so I didn't change so much in `httpd.conf` and `php.ini`.

Below is a list '**What I checked?**':

1. `enctype='multipart/form-data'` is set,
2. `/tmp/` is a `upload_tmp_dir`,
3. `file_uploads` is **on**,
4. File size is in limit, which is set into `upload_max_filesize` (limit is 2MB, but file have 18KB),
5. I tried to use aboslute path,
6. `/tmp/` and `/var/www/html/upload` have chmod set on ***777*** and `upload` owner and owner group is ***apache***,
7. I tried change `upload_tmp_dir` in `php.ini`, but it bring this same result.

Answer (score 1):

It seems SElinux is preventing to write the file. Please check SElinux configuration. If it is already disabled, please share httpd error log.

Comment: I'm not absolving SELinux, but I'm just curious what evidence you see that it's involved?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I didn't know, that `inotifywait` can't show files of other owners, even in `/tmp/`, so temporary files were uploaded into /tmp/, but I wasn't be able to saw it.

Problem was only with SELinux, what I posted in my [linked topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369749/php-move-uploaded-file-permission-denied-only-on-rhel)
a moment ago.